# Patterns for asynchronous authentication (after message is sent)

Tags: authentication, web-service

I'm looking at a scheme where users/servers post messages to each other.  One of the main challenges is to prove "ownership" of a URL - defined as the ability to receive messages.  This can be done with the following pattern:

```
User A  ---(JWT for https://somewhere/userA)---> https://other/userB

https://somewhere/userA <---(JWT for https://other/userB)---  User B
```

At the end of this exchange, User A and User B both have bearer tokens that they can use in subsequence requests to prove their ownership of their respective URLs (proof being that they received the tokens at all).

However, this exchange has to happen **before** any messages are exchanged.  Are there simple patterns that could be used to instead perform authentication **after** a message is sent?

---

I'm looking for something extremely simple in terms of interaction.  In the above case, each server/user decides how to generate/validate tokens themselves - the actual authentication is done by just citing a bearer token (without caring how it actually works inside), and that's ideal.

Comment: Do you need to be able to prevent claiming authorship of comments by anybody but the original poster? If so, have each submission include a unique random number that's kept secret, as a post authorship token. Then later on let the user claim that secret token as his. You can also have the user cryptographically sign the post and have him prove access to the private key.

Comment: A scheme that requires checking a signature requires the receiving party to support whatever signature scheme the sender decides to use, which is something I kinda want to avoid.

Comment: And yes, only authors should be able to claim authorship.  Is your suggestion that User A uses a series of unguessable secrets, until User B initiates authentication and User A replies with a list of all the secret IDs?

Comment: Cloudfeet: I was thinking using the secrets to identify yourself towards the server, which would vouch for you. Otherwise you're limited to a Fawkes signature scheme setup in which you need to involve timestamping

Comment: The goal is that User A is eventually authenticated to ServerB, and User B to Server A, without the two servers or two users having a pre-existing relationship with each other.  (I hadn't heard of Fawkes signatures before - is it [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/fawkes.pdf)?)